# Powershell: how to fetch a single column from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: powershell, multidimensional-array

Is there a function, method, or language construction allowing to retrieve a single column from a multi-dimensional array in Powershell?

```
$my_array = @()
$my_array += ,@(1,2,3)
$my_array += ,@(4,5,6)
$my_array += ,@(7,8,9)

# I currently use that, and I want to find a better way:
foreach ($line in $my_array) {
    [array]$single_column += $line[1]    # fetch column 1
}
# now $single_column contains only 2 and 5 and 8
```

My final goal is to find non-duplicated values from one column.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I don't think anything like that exist. I would go with:

```
@($my_array | foreach { $_[1] })
```

To quickly find unique values I tend to use hashtables keys hack:

```
$UniqueArray = @($my_array | foreach -Begin { 
    $unique = @{} 
} -Process { 
    $unique.($_[1]) = $null
} -End { 
    $unique.Keys 
})
```

Obviously it has it limitations...

Comment: Thanks ! I just found the same solution before seeing you submitted it. For the second part... well... I try to find a better one :)

Comment: There are always few ways to skin a cat in PowerShell. :)

Answer (score 2):

To extract one column:

```
$single_column = $my_array | foreach { $_[1] }
```

To extract any columns:

```
$some_columns = $my_array | foreach { ,@($_[2],$_[1]) }   # any order
```

To find non-duplicated values from one column:

```
$unique_array = $my_array | foreach {$_[1]} | sort-object -unique
# caveat: the resulting array is sorted,
# so BartekB have a better solution if sort is a problem
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried @BartekB's solution and it worked for me. But for the unique part I did the following.

```
@($my_array | foreach { $_[1] } | select -Unique)
```

I am not very familiar with powershell but I am posting this hoping it helps others since it worked for me.